# Errors on uploading file images to server

Tags: asp.net

I want to upload file images to server but I get errors. I can't identify the problem

I use this line of code to upload using asp.net `fileupload` control

```
FileUpload1.PostedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("products_images/")
                                          + FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
```

Comment: Yup - we need an error please

Answer (score 0):

It happens that PostedFile.FileName has the entire file path: "C:\blabla\files\img.jpg"
This is not a valid path to your webApplication, mainly after you concat it with products_images/ --> "products_images/C:\blabla\files\img.jpg". That is why you get your exception.

Try this simple filename treatment:

```
  int lastSlash = FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName.LastIndexOf("\\");
  string treatedName = FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName.Substring(lastSlash);
            FileUpload1.PostedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/products_images/") + treatedName);
```

Regards,